# JAX-RS Jersey Junit Error

Tags: java, spring, junit, jersey, jax-rs

i try to run a unittest for a jax-rs api but i get an error. Some details to my implementation:

The controller!

```
@Path("/webservices")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AController {

    public AController() {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                AConfiguration.class);
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory acbFactory = applicationContext
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        acbFactory.autowireBean(this);
    }

    @GET
    public Response getAll() {
                         something hier...
```

The Test:

```
public class AControllerTest {

    private static final int PORT = 8080;
    private static final String LOCALHOST = "http://localhost";
    private static final String GLOBAL_PATH = "/thesis/webservices/";

    private static final URI URI = getBaseURI();

    private HttpServer httpServer;
    private Client client;

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(LOCALHOST).port(PORT).build();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IllegalArgumentException, NullPointerException,
            IOException {
        httpServer = com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory
                .createHttpServer(URI);
        httpServer.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() {

        client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(getBaseURI());
        ClientResponse response = webResource.path(GLOBAL_PATH)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    }

    @After()
    public void stopServer() {
        httpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

My `<artifactId>thesis</artifactId>` in the pom.xml

when i run the test, i get this error:

```
Failed tests:   testGetAll(AControllerTest): expected:<200> but was:<404>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.466s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 30 22:23:05 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/133M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project thesis: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to pathto/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project thesis: There are test failures.
```

has someone ideas about the problem?
Thank :-)

Comment: Well, you got a 404 and expected a 200. I'd suggest checking to see whether you're serving something on the endpoint you think you are

Comment: which endpoint did you mean? I called the request (GET) with commando and i didn't get an error.

Comment: Off-hand it looks like your controller is mapped to `/webservices`, but you're sending a request to `/thesis/webservices/`. Somewhere you need to map your grizzly server to `/thesis` or change your request path to just `/webservices`.

Comment: i have defined an artifactId (thesis) in the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it. i changed the path to /webservices and it works. Thank's